# 2 divs with fixed images that respond to scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, html, scroll

I am trying to create a scrolling animation with 2 divs and 2 images.
For lack of a better explanation (as you might have guessed from the title) I have made [a quick animation](https://streamable.com/had19) showcasing what I am trying to achieve.

[here](https://fixedscrollingtest-takidbrplw.now.sh/) is a hosted version that I made earlier. I tried to create the effect with the help of parallax scrolling, but it's not quite what I want.
It's a Zeit Now deployment, so you can append [/_src](https://fixedscrollingtest-takidbrplw.now.sh/_src) to the url and take a look at the source code.

Now I am not sure if this is even the correct way to create the animation and to be honest I wouldn't know any other way that I could approach this.
So I am not asking for a fully-fledged answer without any flaws (although it would be much appreciated), but rather a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: ok at least look up how to animate divs, but you might just want to stick to the animation, or change languages because in js it is incredibly long and difficult to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made this quickly so there might be some issues, I tried to make the variables somehow general so you can play with things (check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amrnn/j6mrnc8v/2/))

```js
const body = document.body,
  html = document.documentElement;

const targetImg = document.querySelector('.second');
// our image's initial height
const imgHeight = targetImg.clientHeight;
// the final value for image height (at scroll end)
const imgTargetHeight = 0;
// total height of our document
const totalHeight = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight,
  html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
// visible window height
const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
// starting scroll position we want to start calculations from (at this point and before, our image's height should equal its initial height 'imgHeight')
const fromScroll = 0;
// final scroll position (at this point and after, our image's height should equal 'imgTargetHeight')
const toScroll = totalHeight - windowHeight;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  // get current scroll position, these multiple ORs are just to account for browser inconsistencies.
  let scrollPos = window.scrollY || window.scrollTop || document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].scrollTop;

  // force the scroll position value used in our calculation to be between 'fromScroll` and 'toScroll'
  // In this example this won't have any 
  // effect since fromScroll is 0 and toScroll is the final possible scroll position 'totalHeight - windowHeight',
  // but they don't have to be, try setting fromScroll = 100 and toScroll = totalHeight - windowHeight - 100  for example to see the difference.
  // the next line is just a shorthand for:
  // if (scrollPos <= fromScroll) {
  //   scrollPos = fromScroll;
  // } else if (scrollPos >= toScroll) {
  //   scrollPos = toScroll;
  // } else {
  //   scrollPos = scrollPos;
  // }
  scrollPos = scrollPos <= fromScroll ? fromScroll : (scrollPos >= toScroll ? toScroll : scrollPos);

  // our main calculation, how much should we add to the initial image height at our current scroll position.
  const value = (imgTargetHeight - imgHeight) * (scrollPos - fromScroll) / (toScroll - fromScroll);

  targetImg.style.height = imgHeight + value + "px";
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 200vh;
}

.img-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.second {
  background: tomato;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50vw;
  top: 50vh;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-container first">
    <img src="https://fixedscrollingtest-takidbrplw.now.sh/luigi.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="img-container second">
    <img src="https://fixedscrollingtest-takidbrplw.now.sh/mario.png" alt="">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it works very well!
Maybe you could add in a comment here and there to explain some of the more complex lines for future reference (mainly talking about line 16 in the fiddle).

Comment: I've added some comments that hopefully explain what's going on.

Comment: Very nicely done! The shorthand was just a bit cluttered up so the additional if structure really helps clearing things up. I guess I did get a "fully-fledged answer" ^^